# I want to remove a broken windows 7 boot option from grub but grub customizer generates an error at startup

Tags: grub2, windows, customizer

I have two options for Windows 7 in GRUB but one is broken and just says "CTRL-ALT-DEL to restart." the other Windows 7 option works just fine.
Here is the error message that grub customizer is giving me

grub-mkconfig couldn't be executed successfully. error message:
 Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-16-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-16-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-12-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-12-generic
Adding Windows
Adding Windows
/etc/grub.d/11_Windows.save: 9: ^K: not found

Answer (score 0):

As root, edit the file `/etc/default/grub`,  remove the bad entry, something like:

```
menuentry 'Windows 7'
```

Then `sudo update-grub`.